# onClick, wait for existing XMLhttprequest() to complete

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm struggling a bit with this challenge...

I need to do three things:

- onclick of a button/form submit, wait for the next page to finish loading.
- And then, wait for an existing API/GET request to complete on the page.
- And then check the results of that API request.

The problem I'm having, is that when I click my button, the next page hasn't even had a chance to finish loading and my API check executes immediately.

I have looked at numerous solutions, async/wait, some suggested not to use setTimeout(). And I still can't seem to overcome the first hurdle, waiting for the page to finish loading and allowing the existing API call to finish.

How can I wait for an existing API call to finish running?

```
let button = document.getElementById("signin");
button.setAttribute("onClick", "fireTracking()");

function ajax(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onload = function() {
        resolve(this.responseText);
      };
      xhr.onerror = reject;
      xhr.open('GET', url);
      xhr.send();
    });
  }
  
function fireTracking() {
    ajax("www.myurl.com/getstatus")
    .then(function(result) {
    // Code depending on result
    console.log(result);
    console.log("fire event...")
  })
  .catch(function() {
    // An error occurred
  });
}
```

To confuse things, the URL of the page is the same.  So essentially, I can't look out for a different URL.

I'm starting to think I might need to use a setTimeout()? IE, wait 1 second and then make a new API call?

Please note, this is code is running on top of an application.  I'm using an AB Testing tool, so I'm essentially trying to get this to work, on top of already compiled code.

Comment: `button.setAttribute("onClick", "fireTracking()");` do not use setAttribute to bind events

Comment: @epascarello Hiya, why not?  It seems to be working well so far...  I'm having to do this via DOM manipulation, because of the application I'm using.  Without inserting an onclick, this won't work on mobile.  I was using an eventlistener before...

Comment: because the proper way is with addEventListener

Comment: I’m not fully following your issue, but [preventing the default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) on a form button is typically useful in these scenarios.

Comment: What is that button? Is it inside a `<form>` and/or does it have a `type="submit"`?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette - Hiya, that button is inside a form `<input name="login" class="button-disabled" id="signin-login" type="submit" ng-class="'disabled'" value="Sign in" ng-click="SignIn()" style="">`

Comment: Just remove type="submit" prop or use event.preventDefault(). By the way, it's better to bind your fireTracking() function to the submit event of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That button is submitting a `form` while triggering your `fireTracking` function.

So... That submit is refreshing your page and the result of the Ajax request is just lost.

You have to [prevent the normal submit behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

So here is the "minimal change" to do from your code:

```
let button = document.getElementById("signin");
button.setAttribute("onClick", "fireTracking(event)");  // Add the event argument

function ajax(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onload = function() {
        resolve(this.responseText);
      };
      xhr.onerror = reject;
      xhr.open('GET', url);
      xhr.send();
    });
  }
  
function fireTracking(event) {  // Add the event argument
    event.preventDefault()  // Add this
    ajax("www.myurl.com/getstatus")
    .then(function(result) {
    // Code depending on result
    console.log(result);
    console.log("fire event...")
  })
  .catch(function() {
    // An error occurred
  });
}
```

**But!** a good practice would be to set an event handler for that button using `.addEventListener()`, like @epacarello mentionned.